# Is there a way to insert a sheet from another workbook without opening an instance of the workbook each time?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that will create a checklist for each of the pupils in my class. I've written something, shown below, that will generate a new sheet based on another workbook and then give the sheet the name of the pupil.

My issue at the moment is that each time the macro generates a new sheet it will open a new instance of the "AS Maths Checklist" Workbook, and this seems like a pretty inefficient way to achieve my goal.

Is there anyway to do this without having to open 20 instances of the workbook.

I'm completely new to VBA so any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook

Set s1 = Sheets("Milestone 1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = 1 To s1.Cells(28, 1)


    fileStr = "C:\Users\Downloads\AS Maths Checklist.xlsx"

    Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Add(fileStr)

    
    wbk2.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=wbk1.Sheets(1)
    wbk2.Saved = True
    
    
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    s2.Cells(1, 1).Value = s1.Cells(5 + i, 1)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        ws.Name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
        
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Open it _once_.  Ie move the `Set wbk2 = ...` outside the For loop (and close it at the end, after the Next

Comment: Is `Sheets("Milestone 1")` in the `ActiveWorkbook`? Is the code in the `ActiveWorkbook`? If not what is the name of the `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: @chrisneilsen Ah perfect, thanks. I suspected I may have done something stupid here

Comment: @VBasic2008, `Sheets("Milestone 1)` is in the `ActiveWorkbook`, but the above comment seems to have resolved my problem, thanks anyway.